# Can I use more than one "USING SCOPE" clause?

Tags: soql, reporting, workbench

I am using this query to get a list of old reports in private folders and I am wondering if I can include public folders also. Here is the query:

```
SELECT Id,name,LastRunDate,owner.firstname,foldername,owner.email,owner.isactive FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE LastRunDate < LAST_N_DAYS:365
```

If I use "USING SCOPE everything" I get a list of report in public folders. I want to combine these into one report.

Can I use more than one scope like this? USING SCOPE everything AND allPrivate

Comment: At least syntactically that's not allowed.

Comment: @JayantDas - you should put this as an answer

Comment: @cropredy Done! :)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @cropredy, rolling up comments as an answer.

Looking at the [SOQL Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm), it doesn't seem you can *join* different `filterScope` values. The `AND` keyword can be only used when you are utilizing that in [`WHERE` clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm).

```
SELECT fieldList [subquery][...]
[TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression[...] elseExpression END][...]
FROM objectType[,...] 
    [USING SCOPE filterScope]
[WHERE conditionExpression]

<<other clauses removed for readability>>
```